# What causes segmentation fault / munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer error here?

Tags: c++, class, segmentation-fault

What is the cause of segmentation fault in this code? Why do I sometimes get munmap_chunk() error and sometimes seg fault?

Are we not able to store / retrieve the objects as shown in the code? What would be a recommended method to achieve a similar result?

Expected:

stores test1 object into a file name "data"

retrieves data from file "data" and stores into test2 object

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class Test{
    int num1;
    std::string str1;
    
    public:
    void get_info(){
        std::cout<< "Enter str1: ";
        std::cin >> str1;
        std::cout << "Enter num1: ";
        std::cin >>num1;
    }
    void store_info(){
        std::ofstream file;
        file.open("data",std::ios::app);
        file.write((char *)this, sizeof(Test));
    }
    void display(){
        std::cout << "Str1: "<< str1 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Num1: "<< num1 <<std::endl;
    }
    void retrieve_info(){
        std::ifstream file;
        file.open("data");
        file.read((char *)this, sizeof(Test));
    }
};
int main(){
    Test test1;
    test1.get_info();
    test1.display();
    test1.store_info();
    
    Test test2;
    test2.display();
    test2.retrieve_info();
    test2.display();
}
```

Comment: The problem is `file.read((char *)this, sizeof(Test));`. Your class is not trivially copyable, you cannot copy over it's memory representation like that. It contains a `std::string`. A `std::string` contains a pointer to the actual string data, when you `read` or `write` you just copy the pointer, not the actually data, and it doesn't work as intended.

Comment: Search key term: serialization. You will need to serialize the object to the stream.

Comment: [Handy reading](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization)

Comment: You'd do better to write just a plain old C-string to your file and then create a new `std::string` from it when you read it back in.

Comment: I usually do a Pascal-style string. First store the length of the string (in an integer of known size and byte order) and then store the string of characters. This allows you to avoid playing [getta-byte-getta-byte-getta-byte-byte-byte](https://youtu.be/c7O91GDWGPU?t=34) until you find the terminator.